# How to initialize array index from another user input?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-10

I need to store my contacts table data which I get through user input like below array:

```
0 => array:5 [▶]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "John Doe"
    1 => "john.doe@example.com"
    2 => "15551-234567"
    3 => "New York, NY"
    4 => "230"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "Jane Smith"
    1 => "jane.smith@example.com"
    2 => "15552345678"
    3 => "Los Angeles, CA"
    4 => "5201"
  ]
  3 => array:5 [▼
    0 => "Robert Johnson"
    1 => "robert.johnson@example.com"
    2 => "8.80156E+13"
    3 => "Chicago, IL"
    4 => "4110"
  ]
  4 => array:5 [▶]
  5 => array:5 [▶]
  6 => array:5 [▶]
  7 => array:5 [▶]
  8 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

And I have anther input tag which I need to index the previous array to store in my contacts table.

```
  0 => "contact_name"
  1 => "Select Schema"
  2 => "contact_number"
  3 => "Select Schema"
  4 => "Select Schema"
]
```

I have used following lines of codes to index it and store it into database. But the problem is I got only first index data of every row.

Means if my tag array input comes contact_name , contact_number I need to get the `$contactToBeInserted` array as below:

```
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "contact_name" => "John Doe"
    "contact_number" => "15551-234567"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "contact_name" => "Jane Smith"
    "contact_number" => "15552345678"
  ]
```

But I only get contact_name in `$contactToBeInserted` array.

```
   0 => array:1 [▼
        "contact_name" => "john doe"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "contact_name" => "Robert"
      ]
```

Why's that? Is there any efficient way to indexing the data and get the exact output I want?

```
public function saveReviewData(Request $request)
{
    $allowedTags = ['contact_name','contact_email','contact_number','contact_location'];
    $contactToBeInserted = [];

    foreach($request->tag as $tagIndex => $tag) 
    {
        if (!in_array($tag, $allowedTags)) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach(array_slice($request->data, 1) as $index => $contactData) 
        {

            $contactToBeInserted[$index][$tag] = $contactData[$tagIndex];

            $this->validate($request, [
                'contact_number' => [
                    Rule::unique('contacts')->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                    })
                ],
            ]);

            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->contact_name = $contactToBeInserted[$index]['contact_name'] ;
            $contact->contact_email = $contactToBeInserted[$index]['contact_email'] ;
            $contact->contact_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '',  $contactToBeInserted[$index]['contact_number']);
            $contact->contact_location = $contactToBeInserted[$index]['contact_location'];
            $contact->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $contact->save(); 
        }

    }

    return redirect('contacts');
}
```

Comment: Because as soon as you obtained the first tag data, you couldn't wait to save this contact.

Comment: `array_combine($keys, $values)` ... would probably make some things easier here and remove one of the loops

Comment: @shingo without saving also i couldn't get the second index data..

Comment: @lagbox cab you modify the code and show me as example please?

Comment: `[^0-9]` is more simply written as `\D`.  Please never present your data on Stack Overflow as `dd()` text -- those triangles are not helpful and volunteers will need to reformat your data before they can experiment with it.

Comment: I mean you should save the contact later.

Comment: Is your intention to make `$allowedTags` effectively `$requiredTags`? Are the fields optional? Are you wanting to apply your flat 5-element array as keys to each row of your 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using two nested loops, but you are only considering the outer loop index `$tagIndex` to access the data in the inner loop `$contactData`. This results in overwriting the values.

Use `array_combine` to use `tags` as key and each `data` as value.

```
foreach ($request->data as $dataIndex => $data) {
    $combinedData = array_combine($request->tag, $request->data[$dataIndex]);
}
dd($contactsToBeInserted);
```

After that, to check if all tags are allowed, use `array_diff_key` . If there are no differences, insert into the array.

```
foreach ($request->data as $dataIndex => $data) {
     $combinedData = array_combine($request->tag, $request->data[$dataIndex]);

     // Check if all tags are in allowed tags
     if (!array_diff_key($combinedData, array_flip($allowedTags))) { 
         $contactsToBeInserted[] = $combinedData;    
     }
     dd($contactsToBeInserted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test my advice as native, runnable PHP, I've replaced some of the Laravel specific components with basic outputting.

It seems logical to me that your "$allowedTags" are *actually* "$requiredTags".  Meaning if any of these fields are missing, then the request should not attempt to save the contact.  For this reason, compare the incoming array of tags against the required tags; if not fully satisfied, do not process the data payload.

The next step is to iterate the rows in the data payload, and map the indexed values to the corresponding property names for each object to be saved.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X3Zro))

```
function saveReviewData($request)
{
    $requiredTags = ['contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_number', 'contact_location'];
    
    $approvedKeys = array_intersect($request->tag, $requiredTags);  // remove irrelevant keys
    if ($approvedKeys != $requiredTags) { // is the mapping array missing required values
        throw new Exception(
            sprintf(
                'Request did not include required tags: %s',
                implode(', ', array_diff($requiredTags, $request->tag))
            )
        );
    }

    foreach ($request->data as $row) {
        /*
        $this->validate($request, [
            'contact_number' => [
                Rule::unique('contacts')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                })
            ],
        ]);
        */
        $contact = (object) [];
        $contact->user_id = 1; // Auth::user()->id;
        foreach ($approvedKeys as $i => $k) {
            if ($k === 'contact_number') {
                $row[$i] = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $row[$i]);
            }
            $contact->{$k} = $row[$i];
        }
        printf("Save: %s\n---\n", json_encode($contact));
    }
}
```

Making a request:

```
$request = (object) [
    'data' => [
        1 => ["John Doe", "john.doe@example.com", "15551-234567",  "New York, NY", "230"],
        2 => ["Jane Smith", "jane.smith@example.com", "15552345678", "Los Angeles, CA", "5201"],
        3 => ["Robert Johnson", "robert.johnson@example.com", "8.80156E+13", "Chicago, IL", "4110"],
    ],
    //'tag' => ["contact_name", "Select Schema", "contact_number", "Select Schema", "Select Schema"],
    'tag' => ["contact_name", "contact_email", "contact_number", "contact_location", "Select Schema"]
];

try {
    saveReviewData($request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Output:

```
Save: {"user_id":1,"contact_name":"John Doe","contact_email":"john.doe@example.com","contact_number":"15551234567","contact_location":"New York, NY"}
---
Save: {"user_id":1,"contact_name":"Jane Smith","contact_email":"jane.smith@example.com","contact_number":"15552345678","contact_location":"Los Angeles, CA"}
---
Save: {"user_id":1,"contact_name":"Robert Johnson","contact_email":"robert.johnson@example.com","contact_number":"88015613","contact_location":"Chicago, IL"}
---
```